# File not uploading from react-bootstrap form

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I have a form inside a frontend which takes a file as an input along with 2 other variables.

```
<Form>
                  <Form.Group className="mb-3">
                    <Form.Check
                      type="switch"
                      id="ipfs-switch"
                      label="Add Images to IPFS"
                      onChange={ifpsChange}
                    />
                    <Form.Check
                      type="switch"
                      id="cdn-switch"
                      label="Add Images to Image Kit(CDN)"
                      onChange={imgKitChange}
                    />
                    <Form.Control type="file" onChange={changeHandler} />
                  </Form.Group>
                  <Form.Text id="passwordHelpBlock" muted>
                    You should choose a excel sheet with a single sheet and all the correct columns.
                  </Form.Text>
                </Form>
```

The inputs are set into states using these methods.

```
const changeHandler = (event) => {
    setSelectedFile(event.target.files[0]);
  };
  const ifpsChange = (e) => {
    setIpfsBool(e.target.value);
  };
  const imgKitChange = (e) => {
    setImgBool(e.target.value);
  };
```

When the form is submitted I upload the file and other values for processing by a API also written by me. I use fetch to do this.

```
const uploadMetaData = (e) => {
    console.log(typeof(ipfsBool));
    console.log(typeof(imgBool));
    console.log(typeof(pannel));
    console.log(typeof(selectedFile));
    setIsLoading(true);
    const sc = process.env.REACT_APP_FAST_KEY;
    let formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("file", selectedFile);
    formData.append("ipfs", ipfsBool);
    formData.append("image_kit", imgBool);
    formData.append("city", pannel);

    fetch("https://pythonapi.metropolisworld.io/addCitydata", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
        secretkey: sc,
      },
      body: formData,
    })
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((result) => {
        console.log("Success:", result['detail']);
      })
      .then((response) => {
        
        setIsLoading(false);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error("Error:", error);
        setIsLoading(false);
      });
  };
```

I know the API is working as expected because when I call it from postman it works fine.
However when I call it from the frontend using the above I get and error.

```
[Error] Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 () (addCitydata, line 0)
```

the print out of the result gives me the following.

```
[Log] Success: – "There was an error parsing the body"
```

Can anyone suggest what I am missing here?

Comment: Can you compare your `body: formData` request and the body request which you are passing from **postman** and see if both are same ?

Comment: Can you check what you get from first .then response: console.log(response)? 
Also, do re-check with your headers from postman. Its not always the body.

Comment: @subodhkalika it get ```Promise {status: "rejected", result: TypeError: Body is disturbed or locked}``` from the response

Comment: @QubaishBhatti as far as I can see they match

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end the answer was a simple as removing the `"Content-Type":` header. It turns out fetch automatically sets that in the background, so by overriding it I caused the error.